# XCode 4 - watching values of custom variable during debug

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, macos

I am new to xcode and I just have a quick question. 
In Visual Studio and Eclipse, I can add custom variables to a windows 
and watch its values during a debug session.  I am looking for the 
same feature in Xcode 4, but I cannot find it.  If it is possible in 
Xcode, could you please provide instruction so that I can do what I 
wish to do.  If this is not possible, please let me know.

I am only able to find the window for variables that are "local", or 
"auto", or "all".

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Right click in that same window (that has the toggles for Local, Auto, All) and click Add Expression. Type in the full expression and click Done. The new watch expression should show when debugging in the window in the lower left with an E next to it.

Answer (score 4):

Also, if you don't want to mess about with the IDE too much you can use gdb for this.

Click in  the output window of the debugger and type `po variable_name` and it will print out the value of that variable at that time.

e.g

`(gdb) po mArray`

`(gdb) __NSArray`
`object1,`
  object2
... etc`

You can also use `print variable_name` to get the value of a variable.

Comment: a little additional, usually you can use `po` for print description of an Objective-C objects, and use `p` or `print` for C values(like int) or C++ objects.

Answer (score 0):

To print the variable in console,

```
    NSString *str1 = @"First String";
    NSLog(@"%@", str1);
    int counter = 7;
    NSLog(@"%i", counter);
```

And you want to see with out printing,

1. Put breakpoint at desired position and as its break the running application, take pointer to the variable and it will show you an one lined popup with gray colored arrow.
2. As you point to that gray colored arrow, two tiny arrows with up-down indication will show.
3. As you tap on those arrows, a pop will come and choose first option, **"Print Description"** and it will show you the value of desired variable.